# Auto Login from email link and PHP?

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to create a link that when clicked will login a user automatically and take them to a specific page.

I've thought about creating some sort of hashed string that contains the user's ID, username and a few other pieces of info.  When clicked these pieces of information are looked up in the DB and if validated I login them in and redirect them to a specific page.

For sites like Twitter and Facebook when I receive an email notification and click the link in my email I'm automatically taken to my inbox on the corresponding site. I'm trying to duplicate that behavior...

Are there any security issues with doing something like this or is there a safer more preferred way?

Comment: Is it for one time, like email id validation part of your site?

Comment: @Karthikeyan No, it's every time they receive an email notification from an activity on the site.  I need to login them in and then redirect them to a specific page.

Comment: Generally, sites would ask for password, before taking them to the required page. It is seriously a security issue, if you just auto login with the click from email, unless the user is already logged in, from the system.

Comment: It is better to be explicit, rather than implicit. Idea of having link in email to take user to a particular page, rather than bypassing password, IMHO. You could have a single field alone, in your page, since the username is implicit in this case.

Comment: @Paul - It is definitely a security risk. If you absolutely have to do it, you should make sure that a) that particular link (sent via email) works only once and b) has a clear expiry time set after which it wont work.

Comment: I understand it may be a security risk but for sites like Twitter and FB when I receive an email notification and click the link I'm automatically taken to my inbox on the corresponding site.  I'm trying to duplicate that behavior...

Comment: They don't! You must have chosen remember password or save password so that they directly log you in. Clear your cookies and then try to login by clicking the link I am sure it will ask for password

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to offer this feature to your users, you have to take care of two things:

- The validity of the created url must be set in time (ex: 24hours, 48hours).
- The created url must only work for one specific user.
- (optionnal) The created url only work for one page

I propose this kind of solution to create an url which match these criteria (it's only a proof of concept):

```
<?php

$privateKey = 'somethingVerySecret';
$userName = 'cedric';
$url = 'my/personal/url';
$timeLimit = new DateTime('Tomorow');


function createToken($privateKey, $url, $userName, $timeLimit){
    return hash('sha256', $privateKey.$url.$userName.$timeLimit);
}

function createUrl($privateKey, $url, $userName, $timeLimit){ 
    $hash = createToken($privateKey, $url, $userName, $timeLimit->getTimestamp());

    $autoLoginUrl = http_build_query(array(
        'name' => $userName,
        'timeLimit' => $timeLimit,
        'token' => $hash
    ));
    return $url.'?'.$autoLoginUrl;
}

function checkUrl($privateKey){  
    if((int)$_GET['timeLimit'] > time() ){
        return false;
    }

    //check the user credentials (he exists, he have right on this page)

    $hash = createToken($privateKey, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_GET['name'], $_GET['timeLimit']);

    return ($_GET['token'] == $hash);
}
```

Comment: `$_GET['token'] === $hash`

Answer (score -1):

The general standard for logging in is when a user creates an account your program should create a string of seemly random letters and numbers with a certain php function in php 5.5, and then store this in a file with some sort of pointer based on the username. Then when a user tries to login you use that same function and compare the two strings. The function being [hash_pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) even though this php function supports sha... encryptions do not use those. I salt the hash code with the username. [Here](http://throwingfire.com/storing-passwords-securely/) is an article on all website login and password things. The most secure thing you can do with your website to prevent people from brute force cracking your passwords is to limit the connection speed after a couple wrong password attempt to something so slow it would take longer than the life of the universe to crack after a couple password attempts. If you wanted to make a sort of remember me button store the username in cookies **But never the password** the browser will take care of the remembering password part if you label your form elements correctly.